# Make Spyder use a dark theme for the entire interface

Tags: python, python-2.7, spyder

I am using spyder python 2.7 and i changed the syntax coloring in Spyder black theme, but i really want my python programme to look in full black, so WITHOUT the white windows.

Can someone provide me a good explanation about how to change this?

[Python example of how i want it to be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MO17A.png)

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40595961/how-to-change-the-spyder-editor-background-to-dark] . Duplicate

Comment: Yep. Was about to post that myself

Comment: It is not the same question, I know how to change it in python, however it is partially black. So i was wondering if someone knows how to change it in full black with a code using the package qdarkstyle or something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The complete dark theme is available from Spyder 4.0.0 beta https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/releases

How I did it :

1) In Anaconda prompt,

```
conda update qt pyqt
conda install -c spyder-ide spyder=4.0.0b2
```

2) And if you haven't done it before, go to

```
Tools > Preferences > Syntax Coloring
```

Answer (score 3):

If you can't wait for Spyder 4 - this is what does it for **Spyder 3.3.2 in Windows, using Anaconda3**.

1. Exit Spyder
2. Open command prompt or Anaconda prompt
3. Run `pip install qdarkstyle` and exit the prompt
4. Go to ...\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\spyder\utils and open
   *qhelpers.py*
5. Add `import qdarkstyle` to the top of that file
6. Replace the `qapplication` function definition with below code (only two added lines)
7. Save and close the file
8. Open Spyder and enjoy your dark theme

   ```
   def qapplication(translate=True, test_time=3):
       """
       Return QApplication instance
       Creates it if it doesn't already exist

       test_time: Time to maintain open the application when testing. It's given
       in seconds
       """
       if running_in_mac_app():
           SpyderApplication = MacApplication
       else:
           SpyderApplication = QApplication

       app = SpyderApplication.instance()
       if app is None:
           # Set Application name for Gnome 3
           # https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pyside/24qxvwfrRDs
           app = SpyderApplication(['Spyder'])
           # Set application name for KDE (See issue 2207)
           app.setApplicationName('Spyder')
           app.setStyleSheet(qdarkstyle.load_stylesheet_pyqt5())
       if translate:
           install_translator(app)

       test_ci = os.environ.get('TEST_CI_WIDGETS', None)
       if test_ci is not None:
           timer_shutdown = QTimer(app)
           timer_shutdown.timeout.connect(app.quit)
           timer_shutdown.start(test_time*1000)
       return app
   ```

Comment: This doesn't work very well because i) our icons won't change to a light color and ii) the Help pane remains in white. Besides, this code will be overwritten every time you update Spyder.

Comment: True, it's just a quick and dirty way to integrate qdarkstyle - I'm sure there are more robust ways. I thought I'd share it nevertheless.

Comment: I'm super glad you shared this. It's a quick and easy fix too. Thanks for saving my eyes Dr. Ripper!

Answer (score 1):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) This functionality will be available in Spyder **4**, to be released later in 2019. For now there's nothing you can do to get what you want with Spyder's current version, sorry.

Comment: Spyder 4.0.1 is now available. As per the [documentation](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/releases), install it with `conda install spyder=4.0.1`

Answer (score 1):

Spyder 4 is out now. Dark mode is included ✌

Have a look at the changes:
https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md