# How to use code formatter Black with Spyder?

Tags: python, spyder, formatter

I use Anaconda's Spyder for some visualization. Got used to code formatter called black when I code in Notepad++. Unfortunately, I don't know to use black with Spyder. Does anyone know?

Comment: Check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40595961/how-to-change-the-spyder-editor-background-to-dark hope it helps

Comment: My question has nothing to do with background colour but with formatter black: https://black.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Answer (score 15):

Since Spyder 4.2, there's support for black built in, though it was set to autopep8 by default for me.

To enable black, go to
Tools -> Preferences -> Completion and Linting -> Code Style and Formatting

Under code formatting dropdown, select black

[image: Snippet showing the dropdown for code formatting with black]

Then, you can use the default shortcut Ctrl + Alt + i or click the format dropdown under source tab to format a selection or the entire file.

[image: Snippet showing the Source tab dropdown]

Answer (score 10):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) We'll add an option to use the Black formatter in our next version, Spyder 4.2, to be released in November of 2020.

Unfortunately, there's nothing we can do about it for our current version (4.1.5), sorry.

Comment: Thank you. Is there any other formatter that Spyder is implementing?

Comment: None at the moment, sorry.

Comment: It would be nice to update this answer now that Spyder 4 has been released. Can Black be easily used from Spyder 4?

Comment: @paugier, we changed our mind and decided to add support for Black and other formatters for 4.2.

Comment: I think [this link](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/pull/13295), or something better should be included in the answer, since now it is available and this question comes as a top search result.